# CSS Toggle Radio Switch Customisation

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, switch-statement

I found this CSS Radio Toggle which I think would work well for a section of our site, how would I individualise it so that on is green and off is red?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tstone/RkvAP/3/)

I've tried altering some of the css but cant seem to get is this the bit I need to make two seperate classes of?

```
#bounds input:checked + span {
background-color:#404040;
color:#F7F7F7;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

Thoughts and examples welcome thank you :)

Comment: just change background color for both statements. Your code example is for checked statemed. just `#bounds` will change unchecked statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RkvAP/1304/

```
<div id="bounds">
    <label class="on"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>On</span></label>
    <label class="off"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>Off</span></label>
</div>

#bounds label.on input:checked + span {
    background: green;
    colr: #f7f7f7;
}

#bounds label.off input:checked + span {
    background: red;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, if you want the `background-color` to change only when the relevant radio `input` is checked:

```
#bounds input:checked + span {
    color:#F7F7F7;
}
#bounds label:first-child input:checked + span {
    background-color:#060;
}
#bounds label:first-child + label input:checked + span {
    background-color:#600;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RkvAP/1305/).

Though this approach is dependant on the order of your elements in the mark-up, though it doesn't require the addition of any other attributes.

Comment: Yeah I can do that Just want to be able to have green for on and red for off, if its possible :)

Comment: You want the green (on) and red (off) background-colours regardless of the radio being checked? Or green (on) and red (off) when the relevant radio is checked?

Answer (score 0):

Or May be like this..

```
<style>

#bounds input:checked + span.on {
    background-color: #0C0;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}
#bounds input:checked + span.off {
    background-color: #F00;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}

</style>

<div id="bounds">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="on">On</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span class="off">Off</span></label>
    </div>
```